# Html disappearing divs below image

Tags: css, image, html

I have a problem. I'm making a website, and it has part which is transparent (png image). But if it covers other div, that said div part that is covered disappears. I've tried some things, and nothing helped. So...
Index.html

```
<div id="TopLine">
 <div id="Logo">
  <img src="images/logo.png" width="420" height="248"/>
  <div id="Menu">
  </div>
 </div>     
</div>  

<div id="Main">
 <div id="Content">
 </div>
 <div id="Twitter">
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

base.css

```css
#Main {width:70%; padding: 10px 0 0 0; margin:0 15% 0 15%; text-decoration:none; background:#663333; border-radius: 15px;} 
#Twitter {width:auto; height:auto; max-height:450px; margin: 0 10% 0 60%; background:#00FF00; float:right;}
#Content {width:auto; height:40%; background:#00FF00; float:left;}
#TopLine {width:auto; height:auto;}
#Logo {width: 100px; height:100px; margin: 10% 0 0 15%;}
```

image:

[image: Img]

Comment: What are you even talking about? Posting a random tidbit of code and an image with no **proper** explanation does not constitute a good question. Explain your problem in more detail, and ideally with a live demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: I'm still lost.  This statement "But if it covers other div, that said div part that is covered disappears" doesn't really make any sense.  Which div? Which image?  I see a reference to a logo but not to any type of background image in the code you provided.  If I ignore the words you wrote I can tell that the HTML/CSS you have will not produce that screen shot.  So... what's the issue here?

Comment: Ok. So I've found out that on local host it renders empty space bellow an image, but on http://jsfiddle.net/ and or http://jsbin.com/ it shows up as it should be... Sorry for useless topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is not disappearing, it doesn't have a background. Your "TopLine" element and its children should be inside of `main`, from there you may position your element as you please (probably using `position: relative`)

Comment: Ok. So I've found out that on local host it renders empty space bellow an image, but on http://jsfiddle.net/ and or http://jsbin.com/ it shows up as it should be... Sorry for useless topic.